# How to proportional(Aspect Ratio) image using ffmpeg function?

Tags: php, image, ffmpeg, scale

Why following function is not execute in php ? Same function is using for video. Please correct me if anything wrong with syntax. I have to proportion watermark as per image width and height. If there is any other command then please help me.

```
$command = "ffmpeg -i input.jpg -i watermark.png -filter_complex 
    \"[1:v][0:v]scale2ref=(W/H)*ih/8:ih/8[wm][base];[base][wm]overlay=10:10\"
    -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a copy output.jpg";

exec($command);
```

Comment: this code has a syntax error : you have to escape the double quotes that are inside the command. `$command = "ffmpeg -i input.jpg -i watermark.png -filter_complex  \"scale2ref=(320/270)*ih/8:ih/8\" -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a copy output.jpg";` or use single quotes `'` instead.
Displaying php errors may help you to find simple syntax errors like this

Comment: I tried above but it is cropping image to small not what I am finding. Water mark should be fit whatever main image size. Thanks in advance

Comment: @ᴄʀᴏᴢᴇᴛ
 $command = "ffmpeg -i input.jpg -i watermark.png -filter_complex 
    \"[1:v][0:v]scale2ref=(W/H)*ih/8:ih/8[wm][base];[base][wm]overlay=10:10\"
    -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a copy output.jpg";

Comment: Use `[1:v][0:v]scale2ref[wm][base]`

Comment: @llogan Do you mean ? $command = 'ffmpeg -i input.jpg -i Watermark_logo.png -filter_complex "[1:v][0:v]scale2ref[wm][base]overlay=x=(main_w-overlay_w):y=(main_h-overlay_h)" -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a copy "'.time().'"-output.jpg';

Comment: @ᴄʀᴏᴢᴇᴛ I am find ffmpeg command to blur all faces which are in video. Are you able to help me for it?

Comment: @VipulJethva The comment section is not ideal to ask for something, you should open a new question if you have an other problem. This way, anyone will be able to answer

Answer (score 0):

You are adding downscaling so the overlay will be smaller. Remove the extra stuff:

```
$command = "ffmpeg -i input.jpg -i watermark.png -filter_complex 
    \"[1:v][0:v]scale2ref[wm][base];[base][wm]overlay=10:10\"
    -frames:v 1 output.jpg";

exec($command);
```

Comment: I am find ffmpeg command to blur all faces which are in video. Are you able to help me for it?

Comment: @VipulJethva ffmpeg does not have face detection, but if they do not move you can blur specific areas. See [FFmpeg - Apply blur over face](https://superuser.com/questions/901099/ffmpeg-apply-blur-over-face/901705#901705).

Comment: That can be possible if video have multiple face and it is movement object with other method?

Comment: @VipulJethva Not with ffmpeg by itself. Seems like a job for opencv or something else.